# Render an image before loading the component in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a Vue application in which i display list of events and every event individually, when i visit the page of the selected link i get an error in my console says `GET http://localhost:1337/undefined 404 (Not Found)` then the image loads

i used this method to set the id of the event to the component

```
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        e: {},
        users: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      issueTicket: function(id, user) {

      }
    },
    created(){
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:1337/api/v1/event/find', { params : { id : this.id } }).then(result => {
        this.e = result.body.result[0];
      })
    }
  }
```

is there a way to get rid of this error ? i'm kind of new to Vue JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your frontend code, in order to make clear where the error occurs.

A first wild guess: You try to access an image like

```
<img :src="e.img">
```

However, your e has no .img property until it's loaded. So you might want to consider to set

```
e: null
```

Initially and add a v-if for your page

```
<div class="this is your page div" v-if="e"> 
  <img :src="e.img">
  ...
```

This will ensure that you are not accessing undefined properties of e

In addition you should consider not mixing code styles

```
created() { .. }
```

vs

```
created: function() { ... }
```